# SQL get count of distinct user types in one row per date

Tags: mysql, sql, count, row

I have a list of countries, and for each country I have a table like this (first column: `user`, second column: `user_type`, third column: `date`):

| user | user_type | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | National | 2022-10-01 |
| user1 | National | 2022-10-01 |
| user2 | National | 2022-10-01 |
| user2 | International | 2022-10-01 |
| user3 | National | 2022-10-02 |
| user1 | Unknown | 2022-10-02 |
| user1 | National | 2022-10-03 |

I would like to get all the distinct users of each type, in one row per day, like this (4 columns: date, first_user_type, second_user_type, third_user_type):

| date | first_user_type | second_user_type | third_user_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-01 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-10-02 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-10-03 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

However, If I run this query:

```
SELECT 
date, user_type, COUNT(distinct user) as num_users
FROM "country"."table" 
WHERE 
date between '2022-10-01' AND '2022-10-03' 
GROUP BY date, user_type 
ORDER BY date, user_type
```

Then I obtain the correct results but with the same date in different rows, like this:

| date | user_type | num_users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-01 | National | 2 |
| 2022-10-01 | International | 1 |
| 2022-10-01 | Unknown | 0 |
| 2022-10-02 | National | 1 |
| 2022-10-02 | International | 0 |
| 2022-10-02 | Unknown | 1 |
| 2022-10-03 | National | 1 |
| 2022-10-03 | International | 0 |
| 2022-10-03 | Unknown | 0 |

But there is an additional difficulty: there are 3 `user_types` globally: "National", "International" and "Unknown", but the problem is that some countries only have "National", or "National" and "Unknown" (no "International"), and I would like the result to appear with a 0 (even if that `user_type` do not exist in that country).
The query should be the same for all conutries, only changing "`country`".

(P.S: the query should be run into AWS Athena)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional aggregation should do it here:

```
SELECT date_, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT IF(user_type = 'National'     , user_, NULL)) AS numNational,
       COUNT(DISTINCT IF(user_type = 'International', user_, NULL)) AS numInternational,
       COUNT(DISTINCT IF(user_type = 'Unknown'      , user_, NULL)) AS numUnknown
FROM tab
GROUP BY date_
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wkrbH6rrR7Lp1rKEjDXGrz/0).

Comment: Many thanks!!! That was it! I accept this answer beacuse I think it's correct, but my tables are HUGE and still get no results from the query... maybe you know some  trick to speed up?

Comment: In my opinion you can't do much here regarding performance, there's just an aggregation operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN user_type = 'National' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS National,
       SUM(CASE WHEN user_type = 'International' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS International,
       SUM(CASE WHEN user_type = 'Unknown' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Unknown
FROM "country"."table"
WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-10-01' AND '2022-10-03'
GROUP BY date
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: It helps, thank you, but I cannot mark as an answer becuase this query is summig rows, but keep in mind that the same user and the same user_type can appear many times (look at the first 2 rows), I am looking for DISTINCT users of each user_type